# Javafxpackager: Generate all bundles

Tags: javafx, deployment

I am using javafxpackager to deploy a javaFX application, but it only generates a deb package, the command line I am using is this:

```
javafxpackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile DebtRegister -srcdir out/artifacts/DebtRegister2_jar -srcfiles DebtRegister2.jar -appclass application.Main
```

I am using ubuntu and I do not wish to use windows for packaging.
Where is the mistake in my command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First please note that the [javafxpackager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javafxpackager.html) has been renamed to [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html).

Regarding your question, please see the documentation:

> all: Runs all of the installers for the platform on which it is
>   running, and creates a disk image for the application.

You will have to run javapackager on every supported platform.